# mysql_fetch_assoc '1' at the end of the loop

Tags: php, html

I have strange problem. I am showing these links to interact with them via jQuery and at the very end it always puts symbol "1" for some reason. I've looked through all my pages and this was the one that caused it. Can you please explain why and how can I avoid that? It does not matter what I select from cat, 0 or any other viable id...
P.S.
I know that code is not complete, but this is just draft to make it all work together...

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cat WHERE catSubID = 0";

$result = mysql_query($sql)
or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 ?>
    <a href="#" class="list" id="btn<?=$row['catID']?>"><?=$row['catName']?></a>
    <?
}
```

Output: http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/5640/outputfb.png

Comment: Why are you running the query twice? You should post complete code in case you left out anything that could be the real cause for the issue.

Comment: Can you show an example of how your HTML output looks?

Comment: Yea didn't saw that, anyway it didn't helped. This is my complete code for this page

Comment: Okey I've added screenshot with visible and code output in it.

Comment: All the output of the loop is wrapped in a link. The 1 is not so it's not printed in the loop.  
After the last iteration mysql_fetch_assoc() returns false. The boolean value of an assignment is the assigned value, thus the while condition is false *but nothing gets printed*.  
The 1 gets printed anywhere further down your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unexpected `1` in your output is usually caused by an unwanted `true` result showing up, for example

```
echo var_dump($foo);
```

would show an unwanted `1`, because it doesn't return its output - it **echoes** its output, and returns a boolean success indicator.

The code that outputs the unwanted digit is NOT apparent in your question, but this is most likely what you need to look for.

Comment: Given that image shows more html that the above code snippet's generating, there's obviously more code, and this "phantom" 1 is coming from a code snippet not included.